DNS settings for www. when there is also a wildcard * DNS record
I have a CNAME DNS setting for all wildcard domains e.g. *.mydomain.com. I also have an A record setting for www.mydomain.com which points to an ip address. However this is ignored when I type in www.mydomain.com and instead it is redirected to the CNAME wildcard value.
